# grails: include multiple objects in a single list

Tags: grails

I am new to grails and I am kinda stuck; 
I have a controller which looks like this:

```
class MusicController {
...
    def index = { redirect(action:list,params:params) }
    def list = {
        [songView: getSongView(), enableStateProvider: true, setLayout: true]
    }
...
}
```

Now in the same list I want to add another object so it becomes like this:

```
def list = {
    [songView: getSongView(), enableStateProvider: true, setLayout: true]
    [genreView: getGenreView(), enableStateProvider: true, setLayout: true]
}
```

In the view class (list.gsp) how do I separate/call parameters per object?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you looking for this: `[songView: getSongView(), genreView: getGenreView(), enableStateProvider: true, setLayout: true]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add another object in the same list just add it:

```
[songView: getSongView(), genreView: getGenreView(), enableStateProvider: true, setLayout: true]
```

Comment: ah, just like that!! I didn't know I could do that. Thank you so much guys, I will keep working on it and come back if I get stuck again!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for what @James Kleeh as mentioned then you should go with it. (taking into consideration genre is coupled to the song always)

If you want to handle your scenario then you have to use `list` of `maps`.

```
def list = {
    [
       [songView: getSongView(), enableStateProvider: true, setLayout: true],
       [genreView: getGenreView(), enableStateProvider: true, setLayout: true]
    ]
}
```

If I were a newbie to grails and skeptical about using groovy collections, I would start with using data objects to handle this scenario. For example:

```
    def songModel = new MyModelData(view: getSongView(), enableStateProvider: true, setLayout: true)
    def genreModel = new MyModelData(view: getSongView(), enableStateProvider: true, setLayout: true)

    def list = {
       [songModel, genreModel]
    }
```